# How to test Reach UI Menu Button with react testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, react-testing-library

When testing a reach-ui menu button It appears as through RTL cannot click the menu items  displayed via a react portal. It can find the element but no events are fired when calling `userEvent.click`.

I have a minimal [repo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-reach-ui-menu-button-forked-z3ky8) reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the [test case source code](https://github.com/reach/reach-ui/blob/develop/packages/menu-button/__tests__/menu-button.test.tsx#L120), the `onSelect` event handler of `MenuItem` component will be triggered by below helper function:

```js
function simulateSpaceKeyClick(element, opts) {
  let { fireClick } = opts || {};
  fireEvent.keyDown(element, { key: " " });
  fireEvent.keyUp(element, { key: " " });
  if (fireClick) {
    fireEvent.click(element);
  }
}
```

`userEvent.click` does NOT work.

Full example:

`menu.js`:

```js
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import {
  Menu,
  MenuList,
  MenuButton,
  MenuItem,
  MenuLink
} from "@reach/menu-button";

export default function () {
  const [isDownloading, setIsDownloading] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Menu>
        <MenuButton data-testid="action-button">
          Actions <span aria-hidden>▾</span>
        </MenuButton>
        <MenuList>
          <MenuItem
            data-testid="action-button-download"
            onSelect={() => {
              console.log("");
              setIsDownloading(true);
            }}
          >
            Download
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuLink as="a" href="https://reach.tech/workshops">
            Attend a Workshop
          </MenuLink>
        </MenuList>
      </Menu>
      {isDownloading && <p data-testid="downloading">Downloading...</p>}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

`menu.spec.js`:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";

import Menu from "../menu";

function simulateSpaceKeyClick(element, opts) {
  let { fireClick } = opts || {};
  fireEvent.keyDown(element, { key: " " });
  fireEvent.keyUp(element, { key: " " });
  if (fireClick) {
    fireEvent.click(element);
  }
}

test("should be able to click a menu item when open", async () => {
  render(<Menu />);

  simulateSpaceKeyClick(screen.getByText(/actions/i));
  expect(screen.getByText(/download/i)).toBeTruthy();
  simulateSpaceKeyClick(screen.getByText(/download/i));
  expect(await screen.findByTestId("downloading")).toBeTruthy();
});
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-reach-ui-menu-button-forked-7tcbp?file=/src/__tests__/menu.spec.js:0-672)

Comment: thanks for the answer this partially works as it currently relies on the "download" item being the first in the list as it is auto focused by the lib `fireEvent.mouseEnter(element);` is also required in the function for it work on any item in the list.


Do you have any idea why the userEvent.click wouldn't work it looks like onClick is still bound to element